# SQL - Retrieving Row by Row of record from a Column and build a Table of two Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to fetch row by row of record from a Column and build a new table with two columns.

In the original table column there will be a 9 digit Character which i have to pick it as Bill Id. For each bill id there will be some messages. So in my new table, It will be Bill Id and Message as two column.

I have to pick either up to 5 messages beneath the bill id from original table or if i hit a new bill id earlier than the 5 messages.

```
create table #t 
(col2 nvarchar(4000))

insert into #t values
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('Total 5 Bills picked up for Processing'),
('AB358399B'),
('XML Validation Failed'),
('CN290550T'),
('service Call Done'),
('Status : SUCCESSFULL'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('CN290570T'),
('service Call Done'),
('Status : SUCCESSFULL'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing')


select * into #billid from #t
where  len(ltrim(rtrim(col2))) = 9

select * from #billid

select * from #t




-- Expected Results
--Bill          Message
--------------------------
-- AB358399B    XML Validation Failed 
-- CN290550T    service Call Done
--              Status : SUCCESSFULL
--              No Bills Picked up for Processing
--              No Bills Picked up for Processing
--              No Bills Picked up for Processing
-- CN290570T    service Call Done
--              Status : SUCCESSFULL
--              No Bills Picked up for Processing
--              No Bills Picked up for Processing
--              No Bills Picked up for Processing
```

Comment: How do you define the order of your original data? From what you posted this is impossible to get accurate because you have nothing you can order the table by.

Comment: Are you loading from a text file?  If so, can an identity(int)  be added to your import structure to create a proper sequence?

Comment: John you are right, Yes i am loading it from a flat file. I can add a identity column to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that there is **no implicit sort order!!!** The sorting of your result set is random!

Therefore I introduced an `IDENTITY` column...

With SQL Server 2012+ you could use `LEAD` or `LAG`, with 2008 you must trick a bit more...

Btw: I would avoid the *only the first is written* approach. This is something your presentation layer should do...

```
--Your table with an IDENTITY column
create table #t 
(ID INT IDENTITY,col2 nvarchar(4000))

insert into #t(col2) values
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('Total 5 Bills picked up for Processing'),
('AB358399B'),
('XML Validation Failed'),
('CN290550T'),
('service Call Done'),
('Status : SUCCESSFULL'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('CN290570T'),
('service Call Done'),
('Status : SUCCESSFULL'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing'),
('No Bills Picked up for Processing');
```

--And this is the query

```
WITH Only9Chars AS
(
    SELECT ID,col2 
    FROM #t 
    WHERE len(ltrim(rtrim(col2))) = 9
)
,StartAndEnd AS
(
    SELECT o9c.ID+1 AS startIndex
          ,o9c.col2 AS Bill 
          ,nxt.ID 
          ,ISNULL(nxt.ID,999999)-1 AS endIndex
    FROM Only9Chars AS o9c
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 nxt.ID FROM Only9Chars AS nxt WHERE nxt.ID>o9c.ID) AS nxt
)
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Bill ORDER BY ID)=1 THEN Bill ELSE '' END AS Bill 
      ,Details.*
FROM StartAndEnd
OUTER APPLY(SELECT x.col2 
            FROM #t AS x 
            WHERE x.ID BETWEEN startIndex AND endIndex) AS Details
GO
DROP TABLE #t;
```

And this is the result

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
| Bill      | col2                              |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
| AB358399B | XML Validation Failed             |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
| CN290550T | service Call Done                 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | Status : SUCCESSFULL              |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
| CN290570T | service Call Done                 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | Status : SUCCESSFULL              |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|           | No Bills Picked up for Processing |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo ..!! Thank you so much. Just a correction. Due to large file, it takes a while on loading. Will it be possible to load all the lines rather limiting up to 5.

Comment: @goofyui, sorry, I don't understand this... Wich part takes to long and what do you want to reduce to 5 rows/lines?

Comment: this was my initial post : I have to pick either up to 5 messages beneath the bill id from original table or if i hit a new bill id earlier than the 5 messages. ..  NOW I want to load all messages beneath the bill id from original table till i hit a new bill id. I am not sure, whether this condition is already applied on your sql script or not. if it is not applied, then it is good ..!!!

Comment: @goofyui this query takes all 9-char Bill-IDs and lists the next lines beside them. The next Bill-Id is the start of a new group. You might add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Bill ORDER BY ID)` to the output list. This would provide a partitioned line count. Number 1 is the one which is visible...